# Why does 'git' work, but 'git-svn' does not, and how do I fix it?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using 64-bit Windows 7 with git 1.8.3.msysgit.0 installed.

The command `git` works fine, from wherever:

```
PS C:\dev> git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
```

However, the command `git-svn` does not:

```
PS C:\dev> git-svn
The term 'git-svn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ git-svn <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git-svn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The example given above is using PowerShell, but running Git bash gives a similar error:

```
$ git-svn
sh.exe": git-svn: command not found
```

Git is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`

My Windows Path system variable contains `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;`

It appears that `git-svn` lives at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-svn` with no file extension, which is confusing to me since other files in that directory carry `.exe` extensions, although those are generally larger files, suggesting that perhaps `git-svn` is supposed to be an alias of sorts for another command, but Windows does not know that it can be executed.  I'm just guessing there.

Anyway, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute it as `git svn` (with a space, not a hyphen).

A while back, git switched from having all the `git-foo` executables on the `PATH` to just having `git` on the path.  I *think* the core `git` executable knows to take its first argument and construct the relevant `git-foo` command, and look for an executable by that name in the `libexec` directory.

Comment: The tutorial I was referencing was old, and did indeed use the hyphenated format instead of the newer (working) format.  Thank you!